# What happens if you lose your Firefox sync key?

Tags: firefox, browser, sync, bookmarks, firefox-sync

What is the sync key?  What is it used for?  In a worst-case scenario, what if you lose it?

I recently came across the key and don't want to lose it, but have never needed it, either.  See also:

> Hi. Before to re-install Windows, I saved my Firefox Sync Key. After
>   windows installation, I can't to access my firefox sync account to get
>   my bookmarks! It says: unknown account, register! But I have a KEY, I
>   need my bookmarks back!
>
> Help me, please, to recovery my bookmarks back! Thanks.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1040248

I've never run into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was for an old version of the Firefox Sync account (a.k.a. Weave) and was the only way to recover your encrypted data. Nowadays, it is tied to your Firefox account so you don't have/need a key.

[Reference](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219631)

> I work at Mozilla (support[at]mozilla[dot]org) and I'll be happy to answer your questions. The updated help articles don't have information about recovery keys because the new version of Firefox Sync won't require it nor will it require device codes. It comes out on April 29th, so don't forget to update your Firefox if you want to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Back when they were used separately from an account, if you lost it, there was no way to get it back.

Now, as Darren said, It's combined with your Firefox account so unless you're still using an old version of Firefox, you're fine

and don't forget, "Browse Free or Die"